# Need help understanding the way to write a multiple filters with PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql, filter

what i'm trying to do is simple: I have a commerce system plain PHP based, which the users has a list of used items for sell. the conflict starts here: they has some filters controls, and they wish to filter those used items by, let's say: seller location or price, for instence.

One or two filters would be, normally, easy to select from SQL, this way:

```
$location = $_POST['location']; // let's say, California.
$max_price = $_POST['max_price']; // Could be 100$.

$select_used_items_by_filters = mysqli_query($data_connection, "SELECT * FROM `used` WHERE `location` = '$location' AND `price` <= '$max_price'"); 

// Which gives us: Select all used items selling in Califronia, up to a maximum price of 100 USD.
```

Problem is, what if they have a way more than two filters, which they may or may not check some of them. we have to make such a query somehow, but we can't combine the WHOLE combinations, it could takes hours and tons of code rows.

What is the most simple and smart way to deal with that with only one query, using plain PHP (non-object based)?
I searched StackOverFlow and found some ways. only is, thanks to those posts, I can say I have the code for it, but not the actual idea of how it has been done.

I want to actually learn.
Please share your knowledge with me, and with future people that watching that post who has the same issue :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check each input and then append to the query if they have any value, or whatever rule you are using. And this code is vulnerable to SQL injection attack.

Comment: First thing you should learn parameterized queries. That prevents a lot of errors and the possibility of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks guys. actually it was just an example. my actual code is 2-way checked by both PHP and JS and other filters. please, let's stay on topic, it means alot to me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please do pay attention to the comments about SQL injection. That's not what your question is about, but if this code is on the internet, it's pretty much certain that your site has been compromised.

The way I've implemented this is for the query to be a concatenation of "in" statements, one for each filter. Your current example would become (please fix up the SQL injection risks!)

```
Select *
from used
where ID in
(select ID from used where location = '$location')
and ID in
(select ID from used where price <= $max_price)
```

For each filter element, you can the define the `in` query. Some will be singular, like maximum price; some might be `in` queries like colour; some might be complex geo calculations like max distance.
You concatenate those `and ID in` queries to your main query; the `AND` function means only records which match all subqueries will be returned.

So, your SQL might end up as:

```
Select *
from used
where ID in
(select ID from used where location = '$location')
and ID in
(select ID from used where price <= $max_price)
and ID in 
(select ID from used where colour = 'red')
and ID in 
(select ID from used where category = 'clothing')
```

Please, please fix your SQL injection problems.

Comment: Can you please describe the multiple query by code? i'm not so sure I understand yet. 
Also about the SQL injection thing - don't worry, my actual code is very stiff and protected. that code you just saw has been writted in 1 min just for the sake of explaination. thank you, tho.